# JPA: ignore field on select, but update(Hibernate Save or Update)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've a situation where I need to save or update user data but not want to include one field while fetching(lastUpdateTime). But while updating the row, I want to update the row if any changes are there with the lastUpdateTime column.

I saw other posts and came to know that updatable=false is the way to exclude update, but is there anything which is like 'selectable=false' or something like this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Save Or Update Code**

```
public void insertData(Table obj) {
    Session session = DbConnectionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        // _log.error(ex,ex);
        obj = null;
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to Insert into Table");
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

**Code Used to Insert Data**

```
insertData(objectList.get(i));
```

> objectList contains the lastUpdateTime as well.

Comment: You should concider using JPA Projection to select less data than your "full entity" contain.

Comment: Any reference for that?

Comment: Any Web Search Engine can hel you : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/projections or http://jpaprojections.sourceforge.net

Comment: I still can't understand how this projection is going to be utilized? I don't have any select query. I'm using the save or update method only. Is this going to be used into the ORM? I've around 70 columns in the table and while save or update I need it to read the values of 69 fields.

Comment: How do you set lastUpdateTime in your entity?

Comment: At this time I'm setting it manually. Its a Timestamp.

Comment: @Learner, I'm not sure I clearly understood your use case. You whant to insert or update data into your DB throught your persistence framwork and without selecting the whole row during the SaveOrUpdate action ?

Comment: Okay. Let me explain the case. I have a set of millions of users, which gets created as well as updated. Based on a scheduler I have to update/insert the rows only for who any update is found or is a new entry. So in my case, since the lastupdatedTime is changed, it updates the row even if no other field is updated. I want to update the row only in case there is an update other than lastUpdateTime. And if there is a change the row gets updated with lastUpdateTime(Save or Update).

Comment: I've tried to make updatable& insertable false in the lastUpdateTime field & add `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, selectBeforeUpdate = true)` . But this also somehow not working as the rows are getting updated on the DB side. How I can say this is because I've implemented a trigger on DB side which updates the same table with the lastUpdateTime when an update or insert comes to the table.